# Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 while installing jugglingdb-postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, npm, jugglingdb

I am getting this error while installing jugglingdb-postgres in my ubuntu.help me to sort out this problem.Using Python 2.7.4 in my ubuntu.

```
gyp: Call to 'pg_config --libdir' returned exit status 1.
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/satyam/project/node_modules/jugglingdb-postgres/node_modules/pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg_config` isn't on your `PATH`.

Adjust your `PATH` then make sure that running:

```
pg_config --version
```

works, and reports the correct PostgreSQL version, then try again.

To locate `pg_config`:

```
locate */pg_config
```

Comment: PATH of what,sorry but I am not getting,Are you telling about pg_config file of postgresql 9.1?

Comment: @SatyamKoyani `PATH` is an environment variable. UNIX 101. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable) or http://askubuntu.com/questions/141718/what-is-path-environment-variable-and-how-to-add-it